# SAML Request Signature verification failure

Tags: java, x509certificate, saml, signature, saml-2.0

Can the following part of a SAML request lead to a Caused by: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Signature verification failed exception?

`<ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:X509Data/>
</ds:KeyInfo>`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. The `Signature/KeyInfo/X509Data` element in a SAML message should contain a certificate with the public key that was used to signed the SAML message. In your case it is empty which may lead to a signature verification error.

Also note that normally you would established the authenticity of public key(s) for the sender in advance over an out-of-band trusted channel. You would only use the `X509Data` as a pointer to the actual public key in case you have received more than one or you use a Certificate Authority.

Note that the `KeyInfo` element is optional and the sender may omit it from the `Signature`, which would be a better choice in this case than providing an empty element because it may break receiving software. The latter seems to be happening here. FWIW: the vast majority of SAML implementations always includes the `KeyInfo` element.

Comment: See this as well, let me know if this is because of the same thing... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793294/after-upgrading-to-java-8-from-java-7-signature-references-fail