# After upgrading to Java 8 from Java 7 signature references fail

Tags: java, certificate, saml

I have upgraded Java from 7 to 8 recently and i am facing issue with one of the services that are using saml requests.
I get the following Error:

```
Jan 05, 2015 3:42:06 PM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference validate
FINE: Expected digest: oOGa8vH4D/IUG4rulEBiQMbc5as=
Jan 05, 2015 3:42:06 PM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference validate
FINE: Actual digest: 7JwuVaoeBca7IojrS0ULT3Fra0Y=
Jan 05, 2015 3:42:06 PM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature validate
FINE: Reference[#XID-44b4791a2aab445ea06a1ae7fd6676c2] is valid: false
Jan 05, 2015 3:42:06 PM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature validate
FINE: Couldn't validate the References
Jan 05, 2015 3:42:06 PM com.sun.xml.wss.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor verify
SEVERE: WSS1315: Signature Verification Failed
Jan 05, 2015 3:42:06 PM com.sun.xml.wss.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor verify
SEVERE: WSS1338: Error occured in verifying the signature
```

It used to work earlier with Java 7.
Following is the sample request....
Sample Request:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <wsa:To>someURL</wsa:To>
  <wsa:MessageID>XID-d0d2462194b6ced902422691850b50f3</wsa:MessageID>
  <wsa:Action>someAction</wsa:Action>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
   <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" 
ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
wsu:Id="XID-71380b994c47272f6c2e2c31a0a26eb6">MIIGxTCCBK2gAwIBAgIQdGS5YDDbSjiUuMCJUFIPKDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBmMQswCQYDVQQGEwJOTDEgMB4GA1UECgwXS1BOIEN......</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
   <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
     <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
      <ds:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse SOAP-ENV"/>
     </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
     <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
     <ds:Reference URI="#XID-0f11762f41a81b1c00fb6bc112c8d0a6">
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
      <ds:DigestValue>V8ydrq8hUhYDYJKj2MTSwTqEX78=</ds:DigestValue>
      <ds:Transforms>
       <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#STR-Transform">
        <wsse:TransformationParameters>
         <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </wsse:TransformationParameters>
       </ds:Transform>
      </ds:Transforms>
     </ds:Reference>
     <ds:Reference URI="#XID-b2710d2281c8eed3501a59da494fd8fb">
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
      <ds:DigestValue>JYygH6jWBQ0mmKD0wALX4SwZGJg=</ds:DigestValue>
     </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    
<ds:SignatureValue>BBChEf5PWEQlgBXtuI+f6eVOvjDRv8IBsvieQR0oZV2/owShrZafL/xsqyUwaTHKKjiqA8UoStQs09/K4vihsQhxTxf90f6jfzd+UMMyPJzgbn51pS6Sqz6ZFIa1SD....</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
     <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
wsu:Id="XID-cfb3089f3308ae0aa8ff7bd399ff31c6">
      <wsse:Reference URI="#XID-71380b994c47272f6c2e2c31a0a26eb6" 
ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
     </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
   </ds:Signature>
   <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0" wsu:Id="XID-0f11762f41a81b1c00fb6bc112c8d0a6">
    <wsse:KeyIdentifier 
ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID">XID-0f11762f41a81b1c00fb6bc112c8d0a6</wsse:KeyIdentif
ier>
   </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
   <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="XID-0f11762f41a81b1c00fb6bc112c8d0a6" 
Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-12-23T14:53:27Z">
    <saml:Issuer>ABC</saml:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
     <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
      <ds:Reference URI="#XID-0f11762f41a81b1c00fb6bc112c8d0a6">
       <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
       </ds:Transforms>
       <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
       <ds:DigestValue>3RL5/9A9PnbcN1UQlYoex2wmB2I=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
     </ds:SignedInfo>
     
<ds:SignatureValue>gNvBQlMs49fAZ02t4ng68LO6A0rh1MooT1qhhLoel5mt/a2A8xEl9Dr6diS+iv/cuINsEIlq8YMQKbMHE5mQgVQ2XFQPLeK9PX2nMdFzCglR3ZOyd8OsrhiDwb....</ds:SignatureValue>
     <ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:X509Data/>
     </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml:Subject>
     <saml:NameID>urn:app:NUM:693315908</saml:NameID>
     <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:sender-vouches"/>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml:Conditions/>
    <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-12-23T14:53:27Z">
     <saml:AuthnContext>
      <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
      <saml:AuthenticatingAuthority>someAuthenticationAuthority</saml:AuthenticatingAuthority>
     </saml:AuthnContext>
    </saml:AuthnStatement>
   </saml:Assertion>
  </wsse:Security>
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="XID-b2710d2281c8eed3501a59da494fd8fb">
  //body goes here
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you show the actual SAML message and the verification key?

Comment: @Hans Z. added sample request.

Comment: Which SAML/XMLDsig stack/library are you using to verify the signature or in what WSSE framework are you receiving this?

Comment: @HansZ. Axis2 1.5.3, Java8, xws-security 3.1

Comment: It looks like an issue with the canonicalization of the XML message since the digest produced by the receiver after that is different from the digest that the sender produced. I have no idea how that relates to Java 8. Longshot: you may try and update to the most recent versions of all components...? E.g. xml-security-1.5.2 seemed to have an issue with canonicalization.

Comment: @HansZ. we are using xmlsec version 1.4.3

Comment: Can you try a more recent version 1.5.6 or 1.5.7?

Comment: @HansZ. I cant at the moment. as the same setup works for 2 other service providers. Could you please tell me what is the Expected digest and Actual Digest? That would really help!

Comment: the values are in the first two lines of your log; one is the hash of the message produced by the receiver, the other one is the hash of (supposedly) the same message produced by the sender

Comment: @HansZ. Jan 06, 2015 10:44:20 AM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference validate
FINE: Expected digest: 2rK0uFpSrybNgclwzjYolWnVTcM=
Jan 06, 2015 10:44:20 AM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference validate
FINE: Actual digest: kstFhOfN04SpDSy06d2BgReGs78= the sample contains digestValue: 2rK0uFpSrybNgclwzjYolWnVTcM=

Comment: @HansZ. When the client leaves out the Transforms element, the DigestValue is the same as we expect at the server.  So the problem is solved by leaving this element out. Probability of the client not Transforming the data before signing it? Also, Is it possible to include the Transform element in the message but not transform the data?